# Is there any performance gain with FlutterIcons instead of using the SVG directly?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, svg, icons

Is there any performance gain or any other advantage to use [fluttericon](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttericon) or fluttericon instead of just using each icon `svg` directly with [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) for example?

Comment: fluttericon package readme says it should not be used in production, it would be interesting to see what is faster, loading entire font familiy and rendering font or rendering svg. IMO if font file has many fonts than svg could perform faster but I can't say that for sure

Comment: @Ravindra what they say is that you should not use the hole icon dataset they generate as default, they say that you should build your own icon set, not that the library perse is not usable in production, or that is what I undersand.

Comment: It would unnecessarily increase the physical size of an app to use the fluttericon_pkg in production (including all 4000+ icons) assuming the vast majority of those are not needed in the actual app UI. Whether this increased size has any effect on performance, I do not know.

To reduce the size of the icon font, it would be better to use https://www.fluttericon.com/, which generates the same package structure as fluttericon_pkg, but allows you to customize your icon font to include only the needed icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a bit old so you might have already found the answer but here's my take on the subject:

### Performances

Performance-wise, while the package [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) has improved a lot over time, it is still a complex widget which will parse an SVG file and try to render it with its properties. There is still a few issues that are related to performances whenever you try to display a high number of svg widget:

- [Performance to render many SVG in an animation](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/511)
- [SVG asset loading/rendering performance in PageView widget](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/111)

Solution such as [fluttericon](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttericon) or any other package to provide more icons through fonts will always provide better rendering performances as it is as simple as rendering a text.

Now which one to choose between [fluttericon](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttericon) and a font file generated by the [website fluttericon.com](https://www.fluttericon.com/) ?

### Fluttericon (package) vs. FlutterIcon (web)

Well as said by [Ravindra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7210765/ravindra) and [ilikerobots](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5417498/ilikerobots) importing directly the package [fluttericon](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttericon) would increase the size of your application because it would contains all the font packs. It is also mentioned in the package's README file:

> Please note this package is not intended for production use, due to
> the large size. Instead, it can be used as a development aid to help
> identify/test icons.
>
> For production use, it is highly recommended to use [FlutterIcon](https://fluttericon.com/) to
> customize your icon pack, limiting your icon font to needed icons and
> building your own from custom SVG.

### Conclusion

So the best choice in terms of performance and app size would be to use FlutterIcon and only select the icons you want to include in your application. The package should only be used to try out which icon would fit your needs while developing.

Finally, the package flutter_svg should be mostly used if you need to display some complex SVG that cannot be imported accurately with FlutterIcon.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, about this "select the icons you want to include in your application" how can I select that?

Comment: Another side effect of using FlutterIcon is that multiple people can not work adding icons at the same time on the project, because a merge conflict on the generated font will be done only by Gandalf the gray lol

Comment: By "select the icons you want to include" I mean by using the website https://www.fluttericon.com/ you can choose which icon data you will include in your custom font file. And I agree it will be hard to manage the merge conflict if multiple people are working on the same file, you might want to use multiple font file generated by FlutterIcon to avoid this kind of issue.